# Avoiding examples in cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, dataprovider

Please let me know how can I skip using examples for test iterations in Cucumber? I want feature files should have only test steps and in step definition I want to use something like testng dataprovider for iterations. I tried data provider but since it works with @Test tag, looks like its not a feasible solution. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is not possible because scenario outline works with example table to run the same scenario with the different values. But if you want to reduce the size of example table then I prefer you add data in the JSON file and then add the keys here in the example table and then search for the data with the help of those keys :) In case if you have single line of data then you can use before and after hooks in cucumber and try to update the data with the help of hooks.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but can you add some code to help guide the person who asked the question?

Comment: Sure my friend. If you are looking for the same thing then that would be the great idea. I have already done this thing with yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

First of all Cucumber isn't a testing tool its a tool for collaborative development of behaviour. So you definitely don't want to be writing lots of iterative tests of the same thing using Cucumber. Instead try and test at a lower level for such tests using a unit testing tool. A well written unit test can easily run 1000 times faster than a standard Cuke, so if you have lots of tests of the same thing you can save an awful lot of runtime with this approach.

If for some reason you can't do that then the place to provide data for a test to iterate is in a helper method called by a step definition. Once you are in a helper method you are in your programming language so you can easily get external files, read streams, and loop.  This is a far better approach than using Scenario Outlines and large example tables

You can find out about how to use helper methods and how to call them from your step definitions via cucumber.io and the cucumber slack channels.

If you want to know how to do it in Ruby let me know, and I'll add another answer.